# Can a managed package be an extension of another extension package?

Tags: managed-package, isv, managed-extension

Is there a limitation how deep the nesting of base and extension packages (managed ones) is in Salesforce?

So can Package EEB extend Package EB extend Package B?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no documented limit on the recursion depth possible, but there are other limits that apply to this question.

Execution Time: The entire time for a transaction is 10,000ms; this time is shared. Multiple packages are likely to reach this limit sooner.

Referenced Namespaces: You can reference at most 10 namespaces in a single transaction. Assuming each package in a chain were all dependent upon the same object, the maximum recursion depth may well be 10.

DML Operations: There is a limit on the number of records you can process per transaction; this may affect the maximum number of commands you can chain.